# firebug come home?

Tags: firefox, firebug

For a couple of days I had noticed that the "script" tab of firebug had not been working.  I ignored it because I wasn't working with javascript at the time.

Then the day came I was going to need that script panel, which still wasn't working, so I decided to reinstall firebug.

And now, when it's installed, it's just plain gone.  No icon that I can see, neither on the bottom bar nor the top bar.  No mention of it in the tool menu.  The only evidence it's installed is an entry in the extensions list and a file in the extensions folder.

I've tried googling but have not fond anything that sounds like my issue.

I'm using firefox 6 on Windows XP.

Comment: Try hitting F12, might just be something up with the ui

Comment: For some reason, Firebug changed it's toolbar button (and removed the old one) from the old bug to a blue default cursor over a width, short box. Right-click on a toolbar, select Customize, and look for the icon next to the bug at the large picture of Firebug at top of this page: http://getfirebug.com/html

Comment: This is the button you're looking for (download the raw file to view): http://code.google.com/p/fbug/source/browse/branches/firebug1.9/skin/classic/inspect.png (It's the Inspect icon.)

Comment: @Jared Farrish thanks, thats where it was hiding.  If you want to make your comment an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I've also got the issue with the script tab not working properly. Once you get past the installation issue, I'd be interested to hear whether reinstalling firebug has fixed it.

Comment: @Spudley I did do a reinstall when I was wrestling with this and I think that fixed it, but when I first had this issue I worked around it by giving chrome a try and got myself setup there, and I have yet to feel comepelled to return to firebug :p

Comment: @Matt - hehe, sounds like we're going through exactly the same process.  :)

Comment: @Spudley and Matt - If you have a demonstrable problem with Firebug, I would suggest creating an issue in their bug tracking system so it can be looked into. http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/FAQ#How_do_I_report_a_bug.3F

Comment: @Jared Farrish - The problem has been fixed, I was just remarking on how unexpectedly painless moving from firebug to chrome was.  If in the future chrome dev trips me up, I will switch back to firebug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, Firebug changed it's toolbar button (and removed the old one) from the old bug to a blue default cursor over a width, short box. Right-click on a toolbar, select Customize, and look for the icon next to the bug at the large picture of Firebug at top of this page:

http://getfirebug.com/html

This is the button you're looking for (download the raw file to view):

http://code.google.com/p/fbug/source/browse/branches/firebug1.9/skin/classic/inspect.png

Answer (score 0):

You might try checking if it's profile-specific to start:

http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Managing-profiles

Try disabling any other extensions you have installed?